# LXC mount CIFS => permision denied

Tags: ubuntu, mount, lxc, cifs

I'm trying to mount a shared folder `/disk` from local network with `cifs` to folder `test`, but I get permission denied.

I can ping `192.168.1.x`.

[image: see below]

So what's the problem with `LXC`?

Comment: Resolved the problem according to https://gist.github.com/gionn/7585324